# Reversed light switch

Tags: electrical

Recently had a 48 hour power outage. When the power came back on, two of the light switches that were on when it went off are now reversed. Down is on and up is off. They are both single switches that do not have another switch to operate the light. Never heard of this. Any ideas?

Comment: There have to be threeway switches involved. otherwise this defies the laws of physics.

Comment: [Occam's razor](https://www.google.com/search?q=occam%27s+razor) would suggest that "They are both single switches that do not have another switch to operate the light" is incorrect...

Comment: this isn't a thing that happens. Agree with the other ideas

Comment: Are said switches labeled with "ON" and "OFF" on the toggle?

Answer (score 8):

They *actually are* 3-way switches.  You just don't know about the other one.

Something about the power outage motivated someone to throw switches that your family habitually never throws.  They are the other end of the 3-way circuit.

Look closely for switches that you never use, or switches that you don't know what they do.

Comment: I feel like a buddy and a label printer or stack of post its might be useful here. Test each, label them

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways a non-smart switch can fail:

- Always on
- Always off

"Reverse" is not one of those two. Which means, as others have pointed out, that there is another switch somewhere for each "reversed" switch. During a power outage, people frantically try *everything*, including:

- The switch hidden behind the edge of a bookcase
- The switch behind a door that you can't get to when the door is open
- The switch behind the refrigerator
- The switch in the garage/carport/porch for the outside light (you always use the inside switch because you turn the light on before you go out and off after you get back inside)

etc.

Worst case:

- Turn off the breaker for the circuit
- Remove the cover of the switch
- Turn the switch upside down
- Replace the cover
- Turn the breaker back on

Standard toggle switches (the old kind, not them newfangled Decora things) actually have a little embossed ON/OFF. Three-way switches don't have that. So if you have standard toggle switches, that is a way to confirm that these are three-way switches. (Except, of course, that you can use a 3-way switch on a regular circuit if you are out of regular switches, so ON/OFF guarantees "not 3-way" but not 100% vice versa.)

Comment: While you've got the switch out of the box, take a look at it. If there are 2 screws (plus ground), it's a standard one-way switch and something magical has happened to cause it to work backwards. However, if there are 3 screws (plus ground), then it's a 3-way switch and this is entirely expected behavior.